# Facebook pixel event PURCHASE not registering iOS-sales

Tags: ios, woocommerce, facebook-pixel

We have an Woocommerce site and run ads on Facebook and Instagram. When potential customers click on these ads our website is loaded in the in-app browser that Facebook and Instagram uses. What we've discovered is that the Facebook pixel is not sending any purchase data back to Facebook regarding users on iOS. This again means that it's registered as 0 conversions in iPhone and iPad, skewing the audience and algorithms for optimised ad delivery. (The data comes back correctly on Android and computers.)

We've tried several plugins to see if it's plugin related issue, among them Facebook for Woocommerce, Pixel Caffeine and PixelYourSite. No change there.

What is also interesting, is that the metrics for iOS dropped to zero at the same time I switched from another theme to the Divi-theme (which is a page-builder theme for Wordpress). So it may seem like the error is directly related to the theme, but then again there must be something iOS-specific since it works on all other devices, and the theme change though suspicious may be irrelevant.

TLDR: The pixel tracking works exactly like they should on all devices except on iOS in-app browser where the website is displayed as it should be, but where the pixel is not registering purchases.

Edit: We receive other pixel data from iOS as well, it seems that the order confirmation page is the one that is "blocked". 
Example of landing page we use for our ads: https://www.friskforlag.no/frisk-graviditet/

Answer (score 1):

Received help from Elegant Themes, developers of the Divi theme. There is a bug in the current version of Divi that will be fixed in the next 2-3 versions. The solution was to comment out a line of code in the core > functions.php file, and after that we were able to track purchases on iOS again.